# MFC Error accessing other class‘s NTGraph variable

Tags: c++, mfc

Im programing a MFC SDI programme.

Top zone is View class; Bottom zone is SplitterWindow class with two NTGrpah controls m_Graph1 and m_Graph2.

Now I want to access m_Graph1 and m_Graph2 from View class,but error occures.

```
class CSPlitterWindow: public CFormView
{
public:
    enum { IDD = IDD_SPLITTERWINDOW };
    CNTGraph    m_Graph1;
    CNTGraph    m_Graph2;
}
```

---

```
CSplitterWindow* m_pSplitterWindow；

void CMyAppView::InitialGraph()
{
    m_pSplitterWindow->m_Graph1.SetPlotAreaColor(RGB(255, 255, 255)); //Error Occures
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us about the details of this error or is that a trade secret?

Comment: Error show a messagebox "Access violation at address ******"

Comment: Then I would first suspect you didn't allocate `m_pSplitterWindow` properly.

Comment: I have define `m_pSplitterWindow` in MyApp.h like above. I allocate it in MyApp.cpp and debug it, a new error occured: messagebox shows "Debug Assertion Failed. winocc.cpp line:371". I guess it's a error on NTGraph control.

Comment: Have a look at the call stack when the access violation occurs.

Comment: NTGraph is an ActiveX component. Did you initialize COM correctly? Did you instantiate the controls correctly? Are your dialogs set up OK to host ActiveX? Did you check the example code for NTGraph? Quite frankly, from the way you're asking your question, you don't seem to be ready to do ActiveX controls in C++. Walk first, run later and all that.

Comment: Roel, I have done all u say, and programme can run correctly without access m_Graph1 and m_Graph2 from other class. The problem is when I try to access m_Graph1 and m_Graph2 from other class error occurs.